# Whenever a user is created with profile XYZ: Standard User, it should be automatically added to ABC chatter group

Tags: chatter

I am new to sales force, i don't even any idea about this can anyone please help me with this.

Whenever a user is created with profile XYZ: Standard User, it should be automatically added to ABC chatter group.

Comment: can you share your code. What did you try so far?

Comment: i was planning to do this with process builder. without writing a code

Comment: you will still need to write code to add user to group. Please try to write code and if you got stuck then ask in community.

Comment: @TusharSharma if you can explain why this requires code, and by what code mechanisms this can be achieved, that'd make a great answer. (without writing the actual code).

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke i have added my answer to explain why i will go with code. Please let me know if anything I can add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using process builder automation approach.

But what i don't like in this approach is you have to **hardcoded** the ID. If you want to use this code in multiple orgs then you have to manually handle these things again and again. Also if you want to add different user to different group then you have to create multiple process for them.

So i will go with the trigger. First i write `After Insert` trigger on user and based on their profile name  add them in the group. I will use a custom setting to store Profile Name and Group Name Or Id Pair and then use this custom setting in my code to add users in groups. Because trigger will give me complete control of my code.

Also for now you can also use custom metadata(Although I have used them only once) to store these values and can move the data as well. if you have fixed group name("System admin for system admin profile") then you don't need these as well because you can query the records using name.

**Note:** As I am not sure about this point but if you insert multiple user at once then the process builder will run for each seperatly and each insert will count toward limit. So may be you will hit the governor limit. But i am not 100% sure for this. But will keep this in my mind if i go with Process Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with the Process Builder Automatically

Try to go through this link and work it out...

http://automationchampion.com/2015/05/07/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-24-automatically-add-user-to-chatter-group/

All the Best